# How to "pause" only if executing in a new window?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have authored a batch script that assumes `%1` is a path to a file. At times I would like to use this batch script via drag-drop in Windows Explorer (dragging my target file onto my batch script file), and at other times I would like to run this batch script from an existing command prompt window and provide my `%1` path explicitly (usually just a relative path).

I don't want my script to disappear immediately when "drag dropping", thus I need to `pause`. However, I don't want to have to press `any key to continue` every time when using an existing command prompt window, thus I don't want `pause`.

Is there a way to have the best of both worlds? Can I somehow detect/infer the scenario I'm in, and decide to pause or not pause thereafter? What's the best approach here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this in your batch file:

```
set arg0=%0
if [%arg0:~2,1%]==[:] pause
```

This checks whether the 3rd character of the 0th argument (basically, the batch file name itself) is a colon or not.

Normally, when you drag-and-drop something on a batch file, it's called as: `"Drive:\path\to\Batch File.bat" Arg1 Arg2 ...` However, when we execute a batch file from the Command Prompt we generally do not tend to call it like that, with a quoted absolute path. Thus we can exploit this difference and execute a `pause` only when the colon exists as the 3rd character, implying that the batch file was executed via drag-and-drop. Of course, if you do use a quoted absolute path to execute the batch file from the command prompt, it will naturally `pause` as well.

Comment: Exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Throw a `cmd /k` at the end of your script. In an existing window it will just return to the command prompt, and in a new window it will do the same, keeping the window open.

```
@echo off
echo "some text"
cmd /k
```

Note the /k is to stop it printing the:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
>   Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Comment: +1. This is helpful, though this has the side effect of now leaving open a command prompt, when really I'd like to keep the behavior of `pause` in that I can simply hit spacebar (or any key) to close the new window.

Comment: How about Alt+F4? :P

I don't think there's really any way to differentiate between the two situations unfortunately. Happy for someone to prove me wrong though, would be useful.

Comment: Haha, I actually just tried to close a command prompt with Alt+F4 to discover it doesn't work. -.-